# How can make the event target include its child nodes, in js?

Tags: javascript, events, target

This is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/msjmss4c/5/

Below is the code from Nicholas C. Zakas' book 'javascript for developer'.

I'm beginner in web programming and I think this function is fine.

But its 'target' isn't contain its child nodes.

That's why below things happening.

```
Works O : <a> <li id="target"> text </li> </a>

works X: <a> <li id="target"> <p> text </p> </li> </a>
```

So I want make the scope of target into contain its child nodes.

But I don't know how.

Below is the code.

Is any one here who can touch this code?

```
var Event = {
    add: function(element, type, handler) {
        if (element.addEventListener) {
            element.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
        } else if (element.attachEvent) {
            element.attachEvent("on" + type, handler);
        } else {
            element["on" + type] = handler;
        }
    },

    remove: function(element, type, handler) {
        if (element.removeEventListener) {
            element.removeEventListener(type, handler, false);
        } else if (element.detachEvent) {
            element.detachEvent("on" + type, handler);
        } else {
            element["on" + type] = null;
        }
    },

    getEvent: function(event) {
        return event ? event : window.event;
    },

    getTarget: function(event) {
        return event.target || event.srcElement;
    },

    preventDefault: function(event) {
        if (event.preventDefault) {
            event.preventDefault();
        } else {
            event.returnValue = false;
        }
    },

    stopPropagation: function(event) {
        if (event.stopPropagation) {
            event.stopPropagation();
        } else {
            event.cancelBubble = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you html is invalid `li` can't be a child of `a`

Comment: what are you really trying to do... if you click on a child element you want the parent element's event to be fired?

Comment: yes, it is. I want make the parent element's event be executed when clicked its child element. In this code, target only contains an element. I want make target contains element's child elements too.

Comment: And why <li> can't be a child of <a>? I think it's fine.

Comment: how is your event registration code... can you update [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/msjmss4c/1/) to explain what you are trying to do

Comment: I updated the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/msjmss4c/3/

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're asking, hopefully the following helps. Given the following markup:

```
<p id="theParagraph">Here is a paragraph<span id="theSpan">here is a span</span></p>

<script>

function foo(event) {
  console.log('Event target: ' + event.target.id +
              '\nthis: ' + this.id
  );
}

var el = document.getElementById('theParagraph')

el.addEventListener('click', foo, false);

</script>
```

When the paragraph is clicked on, then its *click* handler is called, which calls the function assigned to its *click* event, setting its *this* to the paragraph. By default, the first argument passed to the listener is the related Event object.

That object's *target* property references the element that the event actually occurred on (i.e. the one that was the source of the event). So clicking on the paragraph shows:

```
Event target: theParagraph
this: theParagraph
```

and clicking on the span shows:

```
Event target: theSpan
this: theParagraph
```

However, if you use Nicholas' *Event.add* method in a version of IE that doesn't support *addEventListener* (or perhaps one that does in quirks mode), it will use *attachEvent* instead and the above will fail miserably (it has *event.srcElement* instead of *event.target* and *this* will be the window object).

To fix that you can modify the function to:

```
function foo(event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  var tgt = event.target || event.srcElement;
  console.log('Event target: ' + tgt.id +
              '\nthis: ' + this.id
  );
}
```

and also modify Nicholas' *add* function to:

```
    } else if (element.attachEvent) {
        element.attachEvent("on" + type, function(){handler.call(element)});
```

but that has been known to create memory leaks in early versions of IE 6, which can be avoided if required.

#### Edit

To find an ancestor by ID:

```
function getAncestorByID(el, id) {
  do {
    el = el.parentNode;
    if (el && el.id == id) {
      return el;
    }
  } while (el.parentNode)

  // Most DOM 'get element' methods return null
  // if they don't find a matching element
  return null;
}
```

Comment: That's good, But I'd like to delegate events. I think if "preset target.id" is not equals with clicked element's id, than go up to its parent, and grand-parent elements until find the equal element.id with "preset target.id".  for() and elem.parentNode(), these two functions would make it possible. but it's hard to beginner..

Comment: To get an ancestor with a particular ID is pretty simple. Every [*Node*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1950641247) has a [*parentNode*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1060184317) property that is its parent. So get the *event.target* and if its *id* isn't what you want, go up to its *parentNode* and check it, until you either find the one you want or run out of *parentNodes*. But since ID should be unique for a document, why can't you get the node directly with [*getElementById*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId)?

Comment: Because I'm learning from this...detour way.. Can you give me an example code that test equals and go up to its parent, grand-parent until find equal id?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.

If you add click event on parents node, you should use `event.currentTarget` instead of `event.target`.

`event.target` is 'which node clicked?'

`event.currentTarget` is 'which node listen event?'

User can click parentsNode or childNode

So, target will change.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30724589)